# CORS error policy in Spring boot and React js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors

I am using React JS as the front end and `Spring boot` as the backend service.
Getting `CORS` error while calling delete service using `Axios`. Added cross-origin in the Rest controller class.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000/"}
```

Can anyone help how to fix this CORS issue?

```
**Error message: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/testdelete' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**
```

My ReactJS code:

```js
return axios({
    method:'DELETE',
    url:`http://localhost:8080/testdelete`,
    data: data,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
```

This is my Spring boot controller code:

```js
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000/"},
methods = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.DELETE,RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.OPTIONS})

@RestController
public class TestDelete {
    @DeleteMapping("/testdelete")   
    public ResponseEntity<void> deleteData(@RequestBody Data data) throws Exception {
        // logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code snippets as well.

Comment: Added code snippet.

Comment: Try  @CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000"}) instead of  @CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000/"}) (without / )

Comment: @Rebai Ahmed -  removed '/', placed @CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000"}) but still not working.

Comment: check my answer , i hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try to add cors configuration for your spring-boot project :

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }

}
```

Comment: All methods are working fine but getting CORS policy error for DELETE method. is there any other configuration for DELETE method explicitly.

Comment: what's the difference between other methods implementation and the DELETE method?

Answer (score -1):

You can add "proxy" in your package.json and set it to the target url

For eg:

```
"proxy" : "http://localhost:3003"
```